# Add Bootstrap Glyphicons in Bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a Glyphicon in a table cell. I'm using a Bootstrap table that has the following skeleton:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I insert the Glyphicon into one of the cells like this:

```
<td>
  <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-magnet"></span>
</td>
```

However It's not working.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you referencing? Can you post the reference to bootstrap?

Comment: It's `glyphicon` not `glyphicons`

Comment: @j08691 Thanks but it is `Glyphicons` on the official website: http://glyphicons.com/

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap, as you said you were, then it's singular. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons-examples. Example https://www.bootply.com/FH67sq2uTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-magnet"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised that it doesn't work with Glyphicon"s" since that's how it's written on the Glyphicons website. I copied the code from there.

Comment: Thank you. The website you checked is correct. But you are using bootstrap css. If you want to use glyphicons.com icons then try using http://glyphicons.com/css/style.css?v=10 , <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-magnet"></span> will work